# Find Exception on Java EE Webservice without log access

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I'm currently working on a webservice running on a glassfish 3.1.2-server to which I only have remote deployment access. The route is basically like this: I develop the webservice on a locally running glassfish server -> I create a war-file with all the needed dependencies -> I deploy the war-file to a remote svn-directory I have write-access to -> the remote glassfish fetches the svn-war-files and deploys them -> I can now run them over HTTP-URLs.

This works okay when my local configuration roughly matches everything on the remote server, however now a few problems have started arising - the local webservice runs perfectly, the remote does not. Instead of getting the wsdl when calling ?wsdl, I get a "resource not available" error. So my question is: Is there any way I can force the webservice to redirect the caller of the url with the param ?wsdl onto an error-page detailing the exception? I'm currently calling java.util.logging, but since I have no access onto the logs that's no help.

Comment: If you have got "resource not available", it seems like more that your war isn't deployed correctly. If you have access to admin console, check that everything is ok otherwise you can check the server.log file at the installation time in order to see what

Comment: Nope, I have no access to the logs at this time

Comment: Ok. Do you have any web pages into application ? If yes can you access them ? If not, try to add an index page with hello world to be sure that web app is correctly deployed

Comment: Yeah, adding index pages did the trick (in telling me nothing was deployed) - I'd still be interested in finding out whether or not I can display exceptions from my webservice in any non-xml form